# How to split wav file into two or more parts using c#

Tags: c#, file, audio, io, split

Here the below code for splitting a large 600mb audio wav file into two parts inside button click event..

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string inputFile = Server.MapPath("~/inputPath/BetterFasterCheaperGovt-HD+720p.wav"); // Substitute this with your Input File 
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    int numberOfFiles = 2;
    int sizeOfEachFile = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)fs.Length / numberOfFiles);
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfFiles; i++)
    {
        string baseFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(inputFile);
        FileStream outputFile = new FileStream(Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFile) + "\\" + baseFileName + "_" + i.ToString().PadLeft(3, Convert.ToChar("0")) + extension, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfEachFile];
        if ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, sizeOfEachFile)) > 0)
        {
            outputFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputFile.Close();
    }
    fs.Close();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('success');", true);
}
```

it splits successfully into two file each of same size i.e., 300mb but the 
part1.wmv is 300mb showing length as 1hr 16min
part2.wmv is 300mb length is 0.

means there is no audio in part2.wav only blank corrupted file is created.

please help me out with fixing the issue.
Thanks!!

Comment: You are aware that you can't just split a wmv file like this? At least you will have to fix the headers.

Comment: [WAVE-File-Processor-in-C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19590/WAVE-File-Processor-in-C) 

or

[Command Line Wave File Splitter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7906/A-simple-C-Wave-editor-part-Background-and-analy)

Comment: what you are doing splits the files sure, but it will work only when they are joint again,  you are corrupting the WAVE header by splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Windows Media Encoder SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmformat/windows-media-format-11-sdk). Something like this:

```
Int32 StartTime = 0;
Int32 EndTime = 76 * 1000; //1hr 16min
String SourceName = "original.mp3";
String DestinationName = "newsplit.mp3";
WMEncBasicEdit SplitFile = new WMEncBasicEdit();
SplitFile.MediaFile = SourceName;
SplitFile.OutputFile = DestinationName;
SplitFile.MarkIn = StartTime;
SplitFile.MarkOut = EndTime;
SplitFile.Start();
```

Comment: we need WMEncoderLib.dll for this..But where is the dll file?

Comment: none of the link in microsoft are working.unable to download it

Comment: have you downloaded and installed the `Windows Media Encoder SDK` ?  here is the link[Windows Media Encoder 9 Series SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23848)

Comment: are you having some firewall restrictions? accept the answer if the code works for you.