# How to split .wav file in two parts in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, wav

I have some .wav files. I need to split it in two parts. Like I have an audio file of 10 min. Now I want to split it in two parts 7 min and 3 min. How can I do it?

Comment: This might help you [How to split wav file into two or more parts using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683916/how-to-split-wav-file-into-two-or-more-parts-using-c-sharp).

Comment: My 2005 article on writing simple WAV files might help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/04/15/desafinado-part-four-rolling-your-own-wav-files/

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773909/split-audio-file-into-pieces